# Wrong GrantValidationResult error

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Inside my IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator

```
if (!user.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
{
    context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidScope, "Phone number not verified");
    return;
}
```

I get the below response when i connect using a user with un-verified phone nb.

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Phone number not verified"
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: Even this line doesnt work: context.Result.Error = "asdasdasd";

Comment: If you think this is a bug, please open an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This appeared to be a bug in IdentityServer and will probably be fixed in the next release (2.2).

**The issue:**

The code you provided sets the result correctly to the validation context in the `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.ValidateAsync()` method. However the Error property in this context was not used as the return value. Therefore the default value of `"invalid_grant"` would always be returned.

I proposed a [fix](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/pull/2127) that would return the outcome on the `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext`.